# Probability: three aged persons problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

> There are three persons aged $50$ years, $60$ years and $70$ years respectively. The probability to live $10$ years more is $4/5$ for a $50$ years old, $1/2$ for a $60$ years old and $1/5$ for a $70$ years old person. Find the probability that at least two of them will survive $10$ years more.

I want to solve the problem Compound Experiments process. I want to use Binomial Law. But I don't understand how to assume the success and failure cases. Please help me to solve the problem in full. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ADG I posted a problem for three aged persons and I request for its solution.

Comment: Note that the probabilities of dying are the same as the probabilities of living, up to permutation of the people.  So the probability that all three live is the same as the probability that none live ($p_3=p_0$); similarly, $p_1=p_2$.  By symmetry, then, $p_2+p_3=(p_0+p_1+p_2+p_3)/2=1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Divide it into disjoint events, and then sum up their probabilities:

- The probability that #1 and #2 and #3 will live is $\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{5}=\frac{4}{50}$
- The probability that #1 and #2 will live and #3 will die is $\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot(1-\frac{1}{5})=\frac{16}{50}$
- The probability that #1 and #3 will live and #2 will die is $\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\cdot(1-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{4}{50}$
- The probability that #2 and #3 will live and #1 will die is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\cdot(1-\frac{4}{5})=\frac{1}{50}$

Hence the probability that at least two of them will live is $\frac{4}{50}+\frac{16}{50}+\frac{4}{50}+\frac{1}{50}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Yep, got two different answers, one of them is wrong... will delete shortly...

Comment: You want to count the case where all three live, but only once... each of the pairs includes that case, so you've overcounted it twice, and so need to subtract it twice.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: I just wrote the straightforward way, and got a different answer, so one of the two ways above is wrong... I will delete this answer shortly...

Comment: @mjqxxxx: I removed the first way, please remove your down-vote.

Comment: @barakmanos Your last comment is uncalled for unless you know for sure that mjqxxx downvoted your answer (and even then, this is debatable...). Do you?

Comment: @Did: Let me look up what "uncalled for" means first... Also, if I do know that it's him (or her) then why is this debatable?

Comment: How do you know then? (At the risk of repeating the question in my previous comment.)

Comment: @Did: Oh, OK, it means "unnecessary", I now understand what you mean by debatable (of whether or not it is necessary). I actually think that it is necessary, whether or not I know it's him (or her). This is because the answer as it stands now is correct, and since there's a good chance that the down-voter will revisit this post, there's also a good chance that they will notice and remove it.

Comment: ?? No, you did not ask "the downvoter if they revisit this post" to remove their downvote, you asked mjqxxx. And this is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the generating function for the number of ten-year survivors:
$$
f(x)=\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{4}{5}x\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}x\right)\left(\frac{4}{5}+\frac{1}{5}x\right)\\=\frac{2}{25}+\frac{21}{50}x+\frac{21}{50}x^2+\frac{2}{25}x^3.
$$
You want the coefficient of the $x^2$ terms plus the coefficient of the $x^3$ term:
$$
p=\frac{21}{50}+\frac{2}{25}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
(In this case this probability must be $1/2$ by symmetry, but the g.f. technique works in general.)

Comment: Please explain the answer in details.